# How do I evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{2^{2^{n}}+1}$?

Tags: summation

The series clearly converges, but I have no idea how to approach it using basic methods. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^nx^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for all $|x|<1$. Now just take $x=1/2$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).